# In Python or Pandas what does "Vern" or "Prior Vern" mean?

Tags: pandas, terminology

I am coding in Python and Pandas.  What does the term "Vern" or "Prior Vern" mean?

[image]

Source http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the context, "vern" means "version," and that 0.11.0 refers to a Pandas version. It's talking about the performance impact from one version of `numexpr` to another.

Comment: this is comparing pandas 0.11 (with numexpr & bottleneck) with 0.10.1 (w/o these libs)

Comment: @Jeff I opened a pull request (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5258) to change this to "versions" (To be honest I wanted to test online editing in github ;-)). Hope it is ok this way.